# Agregar ResultSet con varias filas a matriz en Java

Tags: java

quiero agregar a una matriz el resultado de una consulta **select * from** obtenida en mi **ResultSet**
para después imprimir todos los datos agregados a la matriz, lo intenté pero solo me trae el ultimo registro obtenido de la consulta, a continuación dejo mi código.

```
public class PersonaController {
static PersonaModel perModel = new PersonaModel();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object[][] perBean = obtenerPersona();
}

public static Object[][] obtenerPersona() {
    Object[][] perBean = consultarPersona();
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Este es un dato: " + perBean[j][i]);
        }
    }
    return perBean;
}

public static Object[][] consultarPersona() {
    Object matrizBean[][] = null;
    try {
         ResultSet rs = perModel.validarPersona();
         int cantFilas = 3;
         int cantColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();//sacamos la cantidad de columnas
         System.out.println(cantColumnas + " " + cantFilas);
         Object[][] matriz = new Object [cantFilas][cantColumnas];
         if(rs.last()){//Nos posicionamos al final
              cantFilas = rs.getRow();//sacamos la cantidad de filas/registros
              rs.beforeFirst();//nos posicionamos antes del inicio (como viene por defecto)
         }   

         while (rs.next()) {
             for(int i = 0; i < cantFilas; i ++) {
                 int contadorj = 1;
                 for(int j = 0; j < cantColumnas; j++) {
                     matriz[i][j] = rs.getString(contadorj);
                     contadorj++;
                 }
             }
         }
         matrizBean = matriz;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return matrizBean;
}
```

Aquí dejo el scrip de la base de datos en mysql.

```
create table persona(
id int(5) primary key,
nombre varchar(40));

insert into persona values (1, 'Tania Arriaga Meza');
insert into persona values (2, 'Oscar Yair Bautista Ortiz');

select * from persona;
```

En mi clase modelo donde realizo mi consulta obtengo asi mi ResultSet.

```
    public ResultSet validarPersona() {
    Connection connection = ConexionBD.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs = null;    

    String query = "";

    query = "SELECT * FROM PERSONA ORDER BY ID DESC;";

    try {
        st = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        rs = st.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

No se si se pueda agregar asi como lo pienso hacer, ya que estoy trabajando con consultas de muchos registros y es mejor traerlos todos y pintarlos solo agrgando la posición a estar consultando de uno por uno.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces tres bucles para tratar las filas y las columnas? Con el `while(rs.next())` ya estás iterando por cada fila.

Comment: Para agregar a la matriz el dato, si lo realiza pero repite el mismo resultado

Comment: Lo que me parece que estas tratando de ir a la ultima fila, sacar el numero de la fila, luego volver al inicio, luego iterar por cada fila, luego iterar otra vez por el numero de filas... me parece que te estás complicando demasiado. No es normal calcular las filas de esa forma, estás iterando de más y posiblemente machaques la matriz. Lo normal es iterar con el `while (rs.next())`, que ya te garantiza que va a pasar por todas las filas. Si necesitas un contador por ejemplo para el índice de la matriz puedes iniciar una variable a 0 antes del bucle e incrementarla a cada iteración.

Comment: Tienes razón, estaba iterando de más y hay código de más, agrego como quedó, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba iterando de mas el ResultSet, agrego la corrección, gracias.

```
    public static Object[][] consultarPersona() {
    Object matrizBean[][] = null;
    try {
         ResultSet rs = perModel.validarPersona();
         int cantFilas = 3;
         int cantColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();//sacamos la cantidad de columnas
         System.out.println(cantColumnas + " " + cantFilas);
         Object[][] matriz = new Object [cantFilas][cantColumnas];
         int indice = 0;
         while (rs.next()) {
            matriz[indice][0] = rs.getString(1);
            matriz[indice][1] = rs.getString(2);
            indice++;
         }
         matrizBean = matriz;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return matrizBean;
}
```

Comment: Ahora veo que simplemente te sobra la parte del `if (rs.last())` ya que solo lo usas para calcular la cantidad de filas, y ese valor lo tienes al final del bucle `while(rs.next()` en la variable `indice`

Comment: Listo!, editado, muchas gracias!